# How to remove hash (#) from URL in Flutter web

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

The default URL of a Flutter web project defines a URL containing a hashtag (`#`), as follows:

```
http://localhost:41521/#/peaple/...
```

I would like to remove this '#', looking like this:

```
http://localhost:41521/peaple/
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Related issue [Flutter_web navigation should provide a way to remove hash symbol(#)](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/33245)

Answer (score 124, accepted):

You can now use a **simple package** and a ***single line of code*** to remove the leading hash (#) from your Flutter web app: **[`url_strategy`](https://pub.dev/packages/url_strategy)** (full disclosure: I am the author)

#### Using [`url_strategy`](https://github.com/simpleclub/url_strategy)

You simply add the dependency [as described here](https://pub.dev/packages/url_strategy/install) and then add the following function call to your `main` function:

```dart
import 'package:url_strategy/url_strategy.dart';

void main() {
  // Here we set the URL strategy for our web app.
  // It is safe to call this function when running on mobile or desktop as well.
  setPathUrlStrategy();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Calling `setPathUrlStrategy` is all you need to do

---

The package also ensures that running the code will not crash on mobile (see below). Additionally, this will also run on `stable` if you build your mobile app on `stable` and only web on `beta`.

#### Notes

You need to make sure that you include `<base href="/">` inside the `<head>` section of your `web/index.html` when using the path URL strategy.
This is added *by default* when creating a new Flutter app.

Furthermore, when **deploying** your **production app**, you need to make sure that *every path* points to your `index.html`. If you use tools like Firebase hosting, this is done automatically for you when configuring your app as a **single page app**.
Otherwise, you want to look up how to rewrite all paths to your `index.html` for the hosting you are using.

Essentially, you want to have a single page app, where the HTTP server serves the `index.html` for all paths.

---

The package implementation is based on the manual solution using `flutter_web_plugins`. The benefits of using the package are the following:

- Only need to call a single function.
- No need to use conditional imports (the package does it for you).
- You will not get any missing implementation issues on `stable` (as the web feature is still on `beta`).

Comment: You can redirect all of your paths to index.html by adding thnis to the "hosting" field in your firebase.json:

"rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]

Comment: By default, Flutter uses the hash (/#/) location strategy. what is benefit of hash?

Comment: @cretivecreatormaybenot I'm using url_strategy and when I type in a new url the app restarts instead of just parsing it and update the shown page. Is it normal ? To test it I used this Navigator 2.0 example: https://github.com/carloshwa/flutter-example/tree/navigator_2
Many thanks

Comment: Fantastic, thank you so much! For some reason, that '#' was really annoying me, and it was getting in the way of some specific routing I needed to do.

Comment: Without /#/ every time you change address, the whole app restarts. With it, you just move within navigation system of the app, which is clearly faster and more efficient.
It's probably not a good idea to change the default behavior.

Comment: @AshkanSarlak That is simply not true. If your whole app reloads, your app or server is not configured correctly.

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot It's a simple app served by a basic nginx. So I haven't introduced anything wrong in it.

Comment: All this package does is just export flutter_web_plugins `setUrlStrategy(PathUrlStrategy())` with some conditional imports

So you might as well just use the flutter_web_plugins package

Answer (score 33):

*The following answer is **copied** from Mouad Debbar's explanation on GitHub ([see issue comment](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/33245#issuecomment-705095853)).*

---

Here are the steps to use it once it's available:

Add `<base href="/">` inside the `<head>` section of your `web/index.html` file. This will be added automatically for new projects created by flutter create. But for existing apps, the developer needs to add it manually.
Add the `flutter_web_plugins` dependency in `pubspec.yaml` if it doesn't already exist:

```yaml
dependencies:
  flutter_web_plugins:
    sdk: flutter
```

Add a `lib/configure_nonweb.dart` with the following content:

```dart
void configureApp() {
  // No-op.
}
```

Add a `lib/configure_web.dart` with the following content:

```dart
import 'package:flutter_web_plugins/flutter_web_plugins.dart';

void configureApp() {
  setUrlStrategy(PathUrlStrategy());
}
```

In `lib/main.dart`, do the following:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'configure_nonweb.dart' if (dart.library.html) 'configure_web.dart';

void main() {
  configureApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Comment: Currently it's not available on either master or stable channels. But it's tested to be working on both dev and beta channels.

Comment: This should really be a community wiki because it is just a copied answer.

Comment: I now wrote an answer with a simpler solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65709246/6509751

Comment: Does this work if the base href is something else like `/app/`?

Comment: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/navigation/url-strategies#configuring-the-url-strategy

Comment: I prefer this answer because it does not rely on a package, and it's really just a few very simple changes. Relying on url_strategy package for such simple edits is a bad idea for infrastructure and long-term support reasons.

Answer (score 6):

For those coming in 2023, Flutter now explain how to do this in their [official docs](https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/navigation/url-strategies).
One thing they don't mention though (at the time of writing) is how to update `pubspec.yaml` file.

Step 1: update pubspec.yaml as follows.

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_web_plugins: # add this line
    sdk: flutter       # and this line
```

Step 2: run `flutter pub get`.

Step 3: update main.dart as follows.

```
import 'package:flutter_web_plugins/url_strategy.dart'; // add this import

void main() {
  usePathUrlStrategy(); // and this line
  runApp(ExampleApp());
}
```

Step 4: note Flutter's recommendation for running local flutter web below.

> The local dev server created by running `flutter run -d chrome` is
> configured to handle any path gracefully and fallback to your app’s
> index.html file.

I personally like to run it on a fixed port with `flutter run -d chrome --web-port=3000`.

Cheers!

This helped me resolve a redirect issue when implementing magic-link auth with `flutter_supabase` and `go_router` (I mention this for search-engine crawlers, in case it'll help someone else).

Answer (score 4):

Only for Github pages hosting

This also applies to apps that aren't served from `domain.com/` directly but from some path `domain.com/path/`.

You need to add your repo name to base href otherwise your website won't work.

```
<base href="/REPO_NAME/">
```

Comment: what is REPO_NAME here? the domain name?

I'm not hosting in github-pages

Answer (score 3):

add this in pubspec.yaml

```
dependencies:
  flutter_web_plugins:
    sdk: flutter
```

inside the main.dart file add the cofigureApp in to root of the app and also add this import

```
import 'package:flutter_web_plugins/flutter_web_plugins.dart';

void configureApp() {
  setUrlStrategy(PathUrlStrategy());
}

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  configureApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

restart the web app

out will be like this

```
http://localhost:52299/login_page
```

Comment: by using this, I am unable to move any particular page from the URL. it automatically navigates me to the home page.

Comment: same here as well, why does this happen? and why don't I see anyone tackling this?

Answer (score 2):

If your only concern is for routing, you can do something like this:

```
onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
    List segments = settings.name.split('/').where((x) => ! x.isEmpty).toList();
    String page = segments.length > 0 ? segments[0] : '';
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: where to write this ?

Comment: @NehalJaisalmeria inside your `MaterialApp()` widget

Answer (score 2):

1. Install in pubspec.yaml **url_strategy**
2. Write in main.dart:

```dart
import 'package:url_strategy/url_strategy.dart';

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  setPathUrlStrategy();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

3. If you get an error when you refresh the page, then add file **404.html** to the folder with index.html. Copy the entire contents of the index.html and paste it into the 404.html.
   For some hosts it's enough.
   But some host aslo requires the file ".htaccess".
4. You shoud create in the same folder the file ".htaccess" and write into this file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
```

This solution was recieved from [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D5o0oC2_J80).

Comment: yet another beta projects, based on its semver.

Answer (score 2):

After migration go Router to 5.0  UrlPathStrategy.path is removed

My current version [goRouter 8.0.3](https://pub.dev/packages/go_router)

```
 dependencies:
 flutter_web_plugins:
 sdk: flutter
```

Instead of:

```
GoRouter.setUrlPathStrategy(UrlPathStrategy.path);
```

Replace with:

```
 import 'package:flutter_web_plugins/url_strategy.dart';

 void main() {
 usePathUrlStrategy();
 runApp(ExampleApp());
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found most of the answers above to be a bit confusing. What ended up working for my firebase-hosted website was following this short 4-minute [YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D5o0oC2_J80) by Johannes Milke.

The tutorial outlines a number of options for solving the "#" problem, basically explaining some of the answers above a bit better. My final solution was to

1. Add url_strategy dependency as outlined in many of the answers above.
2. Adding base href="/"> inside the  section of my index.html file
3. Making sure that all paths point to index.html by adding "rewrites": [ { "source": "**", "destination": "/index.html" } ] in my firebase.json.

Answer (score -5):

you can also do this

```
String main_url = url.split('#').join();
```

> eg. http://localhost:31265/#apply?id=1

> output: http://localhost:31265/apply?id=1

Comment: what do you even mean man? provide more details

Comment: The post ask to remove # so u could just split the url around # and then again join it.