# Remove hash symbol ' # ' from Flutter web navigation

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I want to create one simple web application with Flutter web but after I create some simple application with this document I faced with some issue on routing address it automatically add one hash '#' symbol to URL on the address bar,  I want to know how I can remove this sign from URL, In fact, right now I see something like this on browser address-bar : http://[::1]:54587/#/register but I want to achieve to something like this http://[::1]:54587/register.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove hash (#) from URL in Flutter web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59870357/how-to-remove-hash-from-url-in-flutter-web)

Answer (score 3):

**Configuring the URL strategy on the web**

1. Include the flutter_web_plugins package and call the setUrlStrategy function before your app runs:

   dependencies:
   flutter_web_plugins:
   sdk: flutter
2. Create a lib/configure_nonweb.dart file with the following code:

   void configureApp() {
   // No-op.
   }
3. Create a lib/configure_web.dart file with the following code:

   import 'package:flutter_web_plugins/flutter_web_plugins.dart';
   void configureApp() {
   setUrlStrategy(PathUrlStrategy());
   }
4. Open lib/main.dart and conditionally import configure_web.dart when the html package is available, or configure_nonweb.dart when it isn’t:

   import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
   import 'configure_nonweb.dart' if (dart.library.html) 'configure_web.dart';

   void main() {
   configureApp();
   runApp(MyApp());
   }

Comment: I just tried this solution and, while it provided the correct urls while navigating from within the app, trying to visit a page via a url returned 404 errors. I'm hosting on Microsot Azure, if that could be related

Answer (score 1):

If your only concern is for routing, you can check out my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63042805/210417

Basically it just splits the current URL into a List and then removes the empty ones caused by the hash tag.