# How to use deep link in flutter web using navigator 2.0 on my webserver?

Tags: flutter, go, dart

I can refresh(reload) and deep link when I launch debug in IDE(vscode)
However when I published to own webserver(I made web resource from this command 'flutter web build'), My webserver is intercept my url and return 404.. :(
It can  enter from main page only

Webserver is runing on golang and Flutter web using navigator 2.0

How can I solve this?

I can't find reference of flutter navigator 2.0 in web.
Please save my life

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem because removed hash(#) in url

I was follow this
[How to remove hashtag (#) from url in web flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59870357/how-to-remove-hashtag-from-url-in-web-flutter)
but this is cause that problem
When I back to original url(include hash), problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at [this code sample](https://github.com/orestesgaolin/navigator_20_example/blob/master/lib/main_router.dart#L166-L183) that uses new `MaterialApp.router()` constructor to handle url path.

In the `parseRouteInformation` of the `RouteInformationParser` you get the raw url and it's up to you how are you going to interpret the data. For instance, in the above sample the route is converted to object `TheAppPath` and later handled by `RoutePageManager` and `RouterDelegate`.

Comment: I know that.. It's not my point but thank you for comment