# url_strategy does not work in flutter web

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I used `url_strategy`  in flutter web channel stable and beta.

I run flutter web in Landscape its work (image 1)

but when I changed Dimensions to Samsung or motog4 or iphone 5s does not work.(image 2),

this is my code:

```
import 'package:url_strategy/url_strategy.dart';

void main() {

  // Here we set the URL strategy for our web app.

  setPathUrlStrategy();

  runApp(MyApp());

}
```

**Image 1**
[image: image 1]

**Image 2**
[image: image 2]

Comment: Maybe this answer can help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/65709246/14729495

Comment: Thanks Franz I saw this  stackoverflow.com/a/65709246/14729495.  url_strategy work on  web and some phone but when change Dimensions to some phone does not work.

Answer (score 1):

This error occurred because of index.html was old.
I just delete old web folder and create new web folder .

run below code in terminal and create new web folder with new index.html

```
flutter create .
```